# Is there a limit to how far/long you can run thermostat wire before it loses it's ability to work?

Tags: wiring, thermostat

I'm hoping to move my Google thermostat to another location in the same room. The wire will be forty feet long, approximately.  Is there a limit?

Answer (score 2):

##### TL;DR No problem

There is a limit. Everything has a limit. But 40 feet should not be a problem. Even 100 feet really isn't an issue.

Low-voltage thermostat wires (and "Google thermostat" means Google Nest, which is a 24V thermostat) use the wires primarily for signaling and also for a limited amount of power. In addition, the exact voltage is usually not an issue as the signals are just "on"/"off". Assuming you have typical 18 AWG thermostat wire (as opposed to someone trying to make use of 26 AWG ethernet cable as thermostat wire) the voltage drop is simply not an issue.